# using class interface as a parameter in wcf service

Tags: wcf

I Have WCF Service Contract and Using a class interface as a parameter as follow :

```
[ServiceContract(Name = "IFrameworkBaseService", CallbackContract = typeof(IFrameworkBaseServiceCallback))]
public interface IFrameworkBaseService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void InitializeConnection(IClientID clientID);
}
```

but I get the following error :

`The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state`

Can anyone help me by this problem

Thanks
Afshin

Comment: When does the error occur?  Can you post the code where the error occurs?  This has nothing to do with the interface - something went wrong and the channel is faulted.  It can't be used any further - you'll have to abort the channel and open a new one.

Answer (score 0):

I think the concret object you passed in for the IClientID is just unknown to the service.
You have to add it with [KnownType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167.aspx)-Attribute

```
[ServiceContract(Name = "IFrameworkBaseService", CallbackContract = typeof(IFrameworkBaseServiceCallback))]
[KnownType(typeof(MyClientId))]
public interface IFrameworkBaseService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void InitializeConnection(IClientID clientID);
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `[KnownType(typeof(IClientID))]`?

Comment: no - you have to add *all* the concrete types you want to add

Comment: The idea is good but doesn't work like this: KnownTypeAttribute cannot be applied on an interface... You can use **ServiceKnownTypeAttribute** on the ServiceContract instead

Comment: TBH - this is two years old and I do not know if I check (compiled) this - but you might be right - indeed - make it a answer or change mine to help the community - maybe the question can be closed this way.