# How to pass Interface as parameter in WCF service?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have the following however I am not sure this is the correct way of doing it.

```
namespace WCFServices
{
    [ServiceContract(Name = "IService")]
    [ServiceKnownTypeAttribute(typeof(DataItem))]
    public interface IService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void InstantiateThirdParties(string name, IEnumerable<IDataItem> data, IEnumerable<string> modules, IEnumerable<string> states);
    }
}
```

this is the code that uses the interface.

```
namespace WCFServices
{
    public class Service : IService
    {
        public void InstantiateThirdParties(string name, IEnumerable<IDataItem> data, IEnumerable<string> modules, IEnumerable<string> states)
        {
            Process.ExecuteAll(name, data, modules, states);
        }
    }
}
```

and my only object type at the moment is the following.

```
namespace DataObjects
{
    [Serializable]
    [DataContract]
    public class DataItem : IDataItem
    {
        public DataItem();

        [DataMember]
        public CustomerInfo customer { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public LoanInfo loan { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public DateTime loanProcessingDate { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string moduleID { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string processingState { get; set; }
    }
}
```

am I headed in the right direction?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Parameter that does what?

Comment: The WCF service takes in 4 paratmers. One happens to be an interface type of IDataItem. I need to tell the service what kind of objects take that interface correct?

Comment: The only interfaces involved here are `IEnumerable<T>, `IDataItem` and `IService`. What exactly do you mean?

Comment: found the answer on this post...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7213083/using-class-interface-as-a-parameter-in-wcf-service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the KnownTypeAttribute instead of the ServiceKnownTypeAttribute.

Comment: Ok, where do I put this annotation? is it like my answer?

Comment: I think it should work if you put it on top of IService. But normally I would put it on top of IDataItem for better encapsulation.

Answer (score 1):

If the interface in question is your `IDataItem` which is used in the `IEnumerable<IDataItem>` parameter then you need to mark the interface itself as a known type:

```
[KnownTypeAttribute(typeof(IDataItem))]
```

Check this blog: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/domgreen/archive/2009/04/13/wcf-using-interfaces-in-method-signatures.aspx

Edit: Should be KnownTypeAttribute not ServiceKnownTypeAttribute as **papadi** pointed out correctly.

Edit 2:

```
namespace WCFServices
{
    [ServiceContract(Name = "IService")]
    [ServiceKnownTypeAttribute(typeof(DataItem))]
    public interface IService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void InstantiateThirdParties(string name, IEnumerable<IDataItem> data, IEnumerable<string> modules, IEnumerable<string> states);
    }
}

namespace DataObjects
{
    [DataContract]
    [KnownType(typeof(IDataItem))]
    public class DataItem : IDataItem
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok where do I put this annotation? such as below?

Comment: @TylerBuchanan, yes, your own answer seems correct. Does that not work? Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: It says "Attribute 'KnownTypeAttribute' is not valid on this declaration type. it is only valid on 'class, struct' declarations."

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like the following?

```
namespace WCFServices
{
    [ServiceContract(Name = "IService")]
    [KnownTypeAttribute(typeof(DataItem))]
    public interface IService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void InstantiateThirdParties(string name, IEnumerable<IDataItem> data, IEnumerable<string> modules, IEnumerable<string> states);
    }
}
```

With my Object still looking like this.

```
namespace DataObjects
{
    [DataContract]
    [Serializable]   <------ Not having this was my problem
    [KnownType(typeof(IDataItem))]
    public class DataItem : IDataItem
    {
        public DataItem();

        [DataMember]
        public CustomerInfo customer { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public LoanInfo loan { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public DateTime loanProcessingDate { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string moduleID { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string processingState { get; set; }
    }
}
```

here is my interface

```
namespace Interfaces
{
    public interface IDataItem
    {
        CustomerInfo customer { get; set; }
        LoanInfo loan { get; set; }
        DateTime loanProcessingDate { get; set; }
        string moduleID { get; set; }
        string processingState { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I take it back, your answer is not entirely correct. In your service declaration you need `ServiceKnownTypeAttribute` not `KnownTypeAttribute` (`DataItem` class is marked correctly).

Comment: Filled out a SoapUI request for the service and I am getting everything except the data parameter. The list is empty.