# Service method with changing parameter

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a service method:

```
public long InsertMessage(OutgoingInEntity input)
{
    var request = new InsertOutgoingMessageRequest
    {
       Id = input.Id
       ... // fields
    };
    return Util.UsingWcfSync<IOutgoing, long>(client => client.InsertOutgoing(request));
}
```

I want to reuse this method in other context because I want 1 method which call this specific service, but the parameter `OutgoingInEntity` can change. When I call this method with other entities, the fields used in `InsertOutgoingMessageRequest` will be available and I will map like I did with the `var request`  I cannot initiate `InsertOutgoingMessageRequest` in other context.

How can I say this input parameter is like generic and can be used for all kind of entities?

Comment: Set input as Object and then cast it

Comment: Could all the possible objects [implement an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26611750/how-to-pass-interface-as-parameter-in-wcf-service)?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to manage the object you receive you can just do this:

```
public long InsertMessage(Object input)
{
   OutgoingInEntity yourObj = (OutgoingInEntity)input;
   ///.. your code ..///
}
```

Then you can do just the same for whatever you need.